# Monotouch binding for method returning id<Protocol>

Tags: xamarin.ios

I'm trying to bind an api (GoogleAnalytic v2 beta) which expose this method :

```
- (id<GAITracker>)trackerWithTrackingId:(NSString *)trackingId;
```

GAITracker is a protocol so my binding contains this definition

```
[BaseType (typeof (NSObject))]
[Model]
interface GAITracker 
{
...
}

[BaseType (typeof (NSObject))]
interface GAI 
{
  [Static][Export ("sharedInstance")]
  GAI SharedInstance { get; }

  [Export("trackerWithTrackingId:")]
  GAITracker TrackerWithTrackingId(string id);

  ...
}
```

When I call GAI.SharedInstance.TrackerWithTrackingId("MyId"), I get this exception

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'MonoTouch.Foundation.NSObject' to type 'GoogleAnalyticBETA.GAITracker'.
```

All the examples I've found are using protocol as a delegate ([as documented here](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c_types#Binding_Protocols)), but not as a method's return value. How can I create a working binding?

Comment: did you ever get to the bottom of this? I can't seem to get the logigng updating the tracker on google analytics - the stats are all zeroo

Comment: Did you find the solution of this binding issue already? Thanks for sharing!

Comment: No, I never fixed the issue. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have something like this

```
[BaseType (typeof (NSObject))]
interface GAI 
{
  [Static][Export ("sharedInstance")]
  GAI SharedInstance { get; }

  [Export("trackerWithTrackingId:")]
  IntPtr TrackerWithTrackingId(string id);

  ...
}
```

And then to use it:

```
var ptr = GAI.SharedInstance.TrackerWithTrackingId("MyId");
var gaitracker = new GAITracker (ptr);
```

Take a look at the existing monotouch binding for Google Analytic

https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings/blob/master/GoogleAnalytics/binding/googleanalytics.cs